# How to make balls bounce off the edges in Greenfoot

Tags: java, greenfoot

I am learning programming on Greenfoot. I'm creating a scenario that has 5 balls which will follow these properties:

1. The balls must bounce off the edges of the world in such a way that the **angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection**.
2. Each ball must **move at a random speed in each of the X- and Y-directions**, which speed may vary between 0 and 5 pixels per direction when the instance is created but stays constant for the lifetime of the ball.

Any tips on how to get started would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the internet [resources](http://www.greenfoot.org/scenarios/7850) first.

Comment: There's no question here ;)

Comment: As with all questions asked here: What have you tried? How is it not working? What were you expecting?